# SQL query for Time between multiple Events of multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query that can calculate the time between events by multiple criteria. I need the last column to be calculated (days since last event)

| EventId | Date | Location | Equipment | Part | DaysSinceLastEvent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/5/20 | Site1 | XYZ | P1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2/1/20 | Site2 | ABC | P2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3/1/20 | Site1 | XYZ | P1 | 56 |
| 4 | 2/5/20 | Site2 | XYZ | P1 | 0 |
| 5 | 3/5/20 | Site1 | XYZ | P1 | 4 |
| 6 | 2/20/20 | Site2 | ABC | P2 | 29 |
| 7 | 2/10/20 | Site2 | XYZ | P1 | 5 |

The table needs to evaluate 4 main columns, Date, Location, EQuipment, Part to calculate the days since the last event. The above is just an example. There are hundreds of locations, thousands of sites, and thousands of part combinations. I could concatenate Location, Equipment, Part together, but i still need the days between the events of that unique combination.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) tag DBMS , 2) provide expect output , 3) also provide what you have tried (and that output as well).

Comment: Is `DaysSinceLastEvent` the value you want to calculate?

Comment: Yes, Days since last event is what i want to calculate. Just note that there will be multiple events. Ideally i don't have to concatenate Site, Equipment, PArt for a single unique value. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @T.Peter 1) done, 2) the table is the output i'm looking for. specifically the last column where the first 5 columns are what i'm trying to calculate the last column from. 3) I've only been able to calculate for min and max events, but i need every event. I've been able to do it in PowerBI, but i need to have the table from SQL output it.

Comment: "database" isn't a specific "database product". What T.Peter was referring to if you use PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, ...?

Comment: @stretch88 my dear, [database] is not a DBMS (e.g. oracle, sql-server), as it provide nothing more to us than [sql] tag. also if the table you show us is expect output then 1) you should mention clearly this is expect output, 2) provide sample data which you want it to become expect output.

Comment: also about "what you have tried" is provide your `code sample` even it didn't get what you want, because it still provide us what step you have already did, and a lot of time a small adjustment can get the result you want. (p.s. also this make people more likely to help since you do your best rather then "Gimme Codz")

Comment: @T.Peter  ah thanks for the feedback. first timer here, so appreciate the help. Using Microsoft SQL Server management Studio. Let me reformat some of the sensitive information and then i will share what i've tried so far. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a window function:

```
select eventid, date, location, equipment, part, 
       date - lag(date) over (partition by location, equipment, part order by date) as days_since_last_event
from the_table
order by eventid, date;
```

This uses standard ANSI SQL date arithmetic where subtracting one date from another yields the number of days. Not all DBMS products support this, you would need to consult the manual of your DBMS to find the corresponding function.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! Really appreciate it and will be better about the inputs next time. Thanks!